# Whats wrong with this generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to do a Buffer Holder for a big buffer stack.

And the classes are:

Buffer Class:

```
internal class Buffer<T>
{
    private T[] buffer;

    public Buffer(T[] buffer)
    {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public int length()
    {
        return buffer.Length;
    }
}
```

DataPool Class:

```
internal sealed class DataPool<T> : List<Buffer<T>>
{
    public DataPool() : base() {}
}
```

and how I create the bufferList:

```
public Server
{
    DataPool<byte[]> bufferList;
    byte[] = buffer;

    public Server(...)
    {     
        buffer = new byte[ServerConfig.MaxBufferSize];
        this.bufferList = new DataPool<byte[]>();
    }
```

}
Everything ok but i cant add buffer into bufferList like:

```
bufferList.Add(buffer); //This is not working, why?
```

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: No sure what your asking but this line `byte[] = buffer;` should be without the `=` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var bufferList = new DataPool<byte>();
bufferList.Add(new Buffer<byte>(buffer));
```

You have to use `DataPool<byte>` and `Buffer<byte>` since that causes the Buffer to accept a byte array, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the buffer as well:

```
bufferList.Add(new Buffer<byte[]>(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `buffer` is of type `byte[]` and your `bufferList` will inherit `List<Buffer<byte[]>>`.

Try

```
bufferList.Add(new Buffer<byte[]>(buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should also be possible to use your code as it is if you implement an implicit type conversion between `Buffer<byte[]>` and `byte[]`:

```
public static implicit operator Buffer<T[]>(T[] ba)  // implicit digit to byte conversion operator
{
    return new Buffer<T[]>(ba);
}
```

I haven't tested it but something to that effect should be possible.